# Rest Json service receiving clipped Json string

Tags: c#, iphone, json, wcf

We have a WCF Rest Json service hosted on the server and it consume from the native iPad application. Most of the users , it works fine while calling WCF service. But for some users, we found that WCF receives the currupted or clipped Json string. Some part of the Json string is clipped and it failed to deserialize  from the service end.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               UriTemplate = "UpdateDate/")]
        [OperationContract]
        CustomServiceResponse UpdateDate(Stream paymentUpdateModel);
```

Below is the error we are getting  while deserailizing the clipped Json string.

```
There was an error deserializing the object of type Model.PaymentModel. Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: Message, root. --   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
```

Do any body know why the Json string clipped?